# Unknown column error in where clause when using includes

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have this query:

```
includes(:foo).where(foo: { price: 0 })
```

I am calling it from a class called `Recipe`.

Foo's have the decimal type column `price`:

```
>> Recipe.first.foo
=> #<Foo id: 1, price: #<BigDecimal:928b000,'0.0',9(18)>, slug: "something", created_at: "2017-12-05 07:54:29", updated_at: "2017-12-05 13:00:51">
```

I get this error:

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'foo.price' in 'where clause': SELECT `recipes`.`id` AS t0_r0, `recipes`.`foo_id` AS t0_r1, `recipes`.`parent_recipe_id` AS t0_r2, `recipes`.`name` AS t0_r3, `recipes`.`description` AS t0_r4, `quantities`.`slug` AS t0_r5, `recipes`.`created_at` AS t0_r6, `quantities`.`updated_at` AS t0_r7, `foos`.`id` AS t1_r0, `foos`.`category_id` AS t1_r1, `foos`.`price` AS t1_r2, `foos`.`slug` AS t1_r3, `foos`.`created_at` AS t1_r4, `foos`.`updated_at` AS t1_r5 FROM `recipes` LEFT OUTER JOIN `foos` ON `foos`.`id` = `recipes`.`foo_id` WHERE `foo`.`price` = 0.0

Why isn't this working? I am using other queries which are all working perfectly fine.

Comment: @mudasobwa gives me the same error minus the globalize gem stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should replace `foo:` (the name of your association) with `foos:` (the name of your table) in the `where` clause.

```
includes(:foo).where(foos: { price: 0 })
```

Comment: `eager_load(:foo).where(foo: { price: 0 })` or `includes(:foo).where(foo: { price: 0 }).references(:foos)` give me the same error.

Comment: Uhhh.. I am sorry, I did not need to add `references` as I am not using SQL directly, but I missed that you've changed `foo:` to `foos:`. It's working now. Thanks for your assistance!